# ExtJS Combo With Checkbox

Tags: extjs

I want to design Combobox with Checkboxes(inside ,along with data)
What is tha best way to do it
For using lovcombo, which files i have to add and how to download those files.
(my requirment is select multiple fields from combo, need not to show selected values as combo select text)

Please help me

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

you will find a good example here how to implement  it.

[Multi select combobox extension](http://tonylandis.com/code/ext-multiselect-combobox-extension/)